# Internet data citation rules

Tags: blog, copyright, data

I have a site and on some pages I want to add data that is available on other sites, also I will put proper reference to my data that is where I copied it from.

I just need proper rule for it.

Like http://www.prweb.com/releases/2012/4/prweb9358675.htm

I want to add an excerpt from this page and refer this page as reference reading. Can I do copy paste? Is this any violation of law?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to refer to the copyright notices on the relevant sites. For instance, [prweb.com copyright notice](http://service.prweb.com/misc/copyright/) states:

> Vocus, Inc. and/or its subsidiary Vocus PRW Holdings LLC,
>   (collectively “PRWeb”) grant you a limited license to use and/or
>   republish any of the press releases on this site for any legitimate
>   media purpose, provided that you:  (1) reference PRWeb as the source
>   and include a hyperlink to the original release on the PRWeb site; (2)
>   do not modify any press release wording; and (3) do not modify or add
>   hyperlinks, including but not limited to adlinks, within the press
>   release.

This is just a snippet, you need to read it all.

In most cases you should be OK quoting a *short* passage and linking to the source material. However, I would refrain from "copy paste" entire articles - this is what hyperlinks are for.